# How to run a test case in selenium IDE which requires user to fill in certain details

Tags: selenium-ide

I am new to Selenium and exploring the IDE currently. I am supposed to automate a web page which requires user to fill in a row of details(It is a row of fields which asks user to fill in name,email ID , to and from dates etc).

I have created a test case and filled in all these details(recorded in IDE). When I play the test case, I observe that the details I have filled appears below the row and the IDE trying to fill in the same values. It errors out telling Name and email ID exist.

Is there anyway I can test this case successfully? I do not have access to the code nor the database.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to create with new user info each time. I tend to use javascript to create a unique timestamped e-mail...

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>'myemail' + Date.now() + '@testdomain.com'</td>
    <td>emailAddress</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${emailAddress}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an issue with duplicate details, the data appearing below the entry field will most likely be just auto complete. But from what you've described I think you'd need to use different data each time.

[SeLite](https://code.google.com/p/selite/wiki/ProjectHome) is a useful plugin that has an additional extension to it called [SeLite Commands](https://code.google.com/p/selite/wiki/ExtraCommands), which gives you extra commands which will input random data into fields (if you don't have any specific requirements on the data being input) it can generate random text, or random emails as well.

Both can be downloaded from [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/)